# fetch data from mysql but if result 0 redirect

Tags: php, mysql

i have code that work with me good but my problem i need if result 0 redirect as header('Location: checkin.php?identity='.$identity);

here my code

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("xxxxxx")or die("Connection Failed");
//added to prevent sql injection
$identity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['identity']);
$query = "select * from blacklist where identity = '$identity'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "{$line['number']}<br>";
echo "{$line['identity']}</div></td><br>";
echo "{$line['reason']}</div></td><br>";
    }
?>



<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <form method="post" name="display" action="index.php" />
        <b>Enter the register number:</b><br>
        <input type="text" name="identity" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
 </html>
```

Comment: so.. what your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in the first line.
And please use MySQLi.

```
if (isset($_POST['identity'])) {

//here your mysqli connect
//and more

}

<form ....... input
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the query check if number of rows select is 0.

```
if(!(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)) {
    //Your while logic here
}
else
{
header('Location: checkin.php?identity='.$identity);
}
```